# Using Time Intelligence Filter inside KPI with a Scorecard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, dashboard-designer-2013, kpi

I am trying to take advantage of the Time Intelligence Filter inside of a KPI, so that I can add this KPI to a Scorecard and have, say, the last 5 days of data from the KPI in the Scorecard. (I have successfully created Scorecards with KPIs before, but only when the KPI returns a single value.)  When I add the KPI to the Scorecard and refresh, I only get one value, not the 5 I was expecting.  What do I need to do here? My KPI has 2 "columns" - the time (actually the date) and the daily value.  I am using a tabular data source, from a SQL table (actually a view).

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was trying to do. Instead of adding a Time Intelligence Filter to the Dimensional Data Source Mapping in my KPI, I added a Time Set Formula as a child of the KPI in the Scorecard, and used my time formula there ("day:day-5"). This gets me exactly what I was looking for.